# process_time() in python and consecutive calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, datetime, time

Looking at the time.process_time() [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.process_time) in python:

> time.process_time() → float
>
> Return the value (in fractional seconds) of the sum of the system and
>   user CPU time of the current process. It does not include time elapsed
>   during sleep. It is process-wide by definition. The reference point of
>   the returned value is undefined, so that only the difference between
>   the results of consecutive calls is valid.

I am using this module in this way:

```
try:
        startTime = time.process_time()
        callmyfunction()
        performanceTime = time.process_time() - startTime
        print("performance time:", str(performanceTime) )
except:
        callSecondFunction(startTime, x, y)

def callSecondFunction(startTime, x, y):
    # do Something
    performanceTime = time.process_time() - startTime
    print("performance time:", str(performanceTime) )
```

As you see, my code can go to exception handling, which calls another function and passes the start time. By the end, it calculates the elapsed time.

But I do not get how this part affects my measurement?

> The reference point of the returned value is undefined, so that only
>   the difference between the results of consecutive calls is valid

Can you explain by example, what does this means? When does the results become invalid or non consecutive calls?

> the difference between the results of consecutive calls is valid

Comment: the values returned are all offset by some arbitrary amount.  just use it as you are (i.e. once at the start, once at the end, then output the difference) and everything is OK

Comment: @Sam Mason As you see, my code can go to exception handling, which calls another function and passes the start time. By the end, it calculates the elapsed time. i.e. it is not always sequential execution.

Comment: Your code executes sequentially, so I don't see any problem here.

Comment: @ForceBru Thanks. The documentation of the function confused me.